# How to validate if node is ubercart product?

Tags: 7, ubercart

Im sure this is something simple, but I would really appreciate some help with it. How to check by php if the node is an ubercart product? Empty sku field might work but how can it be accessed ?

Comment: What context do you need to know this in? `hook_node_view()` or similar?

Comment: It meant to be a rule for Page manager to customize layout only for nodes that are ubercart 3 products

Comment: Sorry, not really sure why I asked that; as long as you've got a `$node` object in the context it doesn't really matter

Comment: Cant tell if it is good idea but Iv made it with reverse rule and this code `$var = ctools_context_keyword_substitute('%node:product', array(), $contexts);
if (empty($var)) {
    // not product
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most solid way to test would be to check that the node's type is one that the uc_product module considers to be a product node type. You can do that by using the [`uc_product_types()`](http://api.lullabot.com/uc_product_types/7) function:

```
$node_types = array_keys(uc_product_types());
if (in_array($node->type, $node_types)) {
  // The node is a product
}
```

Comment: It is greate idea, Thanks. but for some reason this error shows up on node page `Notice: Undefined variable: node in eval() (line 2 of /sites/all/modules/ctools/plugins/access/php.inc(55) : eval()'d code).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() (line 2 of /sites/all/modules/ctools/plugins/access/php.inc(55) : eval()'d code).`

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The most solid way is to use the function Ubercart provides for just this purpose: uc_product_is_product().